# UIImageViews with Collection cell not sizing properly on viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Making a calendar screen using UICollectionView, with nested UIImageViews that I want to dynamically cover the width of the screen. The cells are formatted in this function (inside a Cell class):

```
func formatCell(imageId: Int){

    let width = self.frame.width * 2 / 3
    let height = self.frame.height * 2 / 3
    //print("width: \(width)")
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width / 6, y: self.frame.height / 6, width: width, height: height)
    if imageId == 0 {
        imageView.image = //image
    }
    else if imageId == 1 {
        imageView.image = //image

    }
    else if imageId == 2{
        imageView.image = //image
    }
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}
```

When the screen is initially loaded, the images are not shrunken to their proper size. cellForRowAt calls formatCell every time a new cell is created. For redundancy, viewDidLoad also calls cell.formatCell() for each cell in the collectionView. Additionally, formatCell() is called for each cell when the screen rotates or the app unwinds to this view. In the two latter cases, the ImageViews adjust to the proper sizing. If I rotate back to the initial position, the imageviews are the correct size, not the initial, incorrect size. I want the cells to be formatted when the screens loads.

Comment: Try calling it in viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear as the bounds of your view are not set at viewDidLoad, so the dimensions are likely to be wrong.

Comment: It seems both of those are not being called initially... which doesn't make sense to me.